# When I add a Modifier, nothing happens

Tags: modifiers

When I click on wave in the modifier list, nothing happens. However when I click on the Subdivision Surface modifier this does work.

After I set the surface modifier to desired setting, and try to add a wave modifier, just the top of the object moves up and stays;nothing else happens.

When I add the wave modifier only, with no subdivision surface modifier, nothing happens. When I click apply in the wave modifier box I get this message," modifier disabled skipping apply. **How can I activate the modifiers?  How can I fix this?**

[image: Picture of my blender]

Comment: You might need a bit more geometry for the wave modifier to deform. The default cube only has 8 vertices. Not much to work with.

Comment: I did add more geometry, and moved the green bar in timeline and it worked. I was following an example on you tube. I was assuming that each modifier when pressed gave an example of its default (animation). I did not know that the time line should be playing for it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have actually selected the Warp modifier instead of the Wave modifier.

For the Warpmodifier to work, you need to select two objects in the "from" and "to" dropdown menus.

If you have trouble with the Wave modifier, try adding more geometry like Samir Rahamtalla suggested (subdivision modifier before the wave modifier or manual subdivision in edit mode).

[Further information (Blender Docs)](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/deform/warp.html)

Comment: I accidentally clicked warp. This is my second day using Blender. I moved the green bar in the time line and it worked. Your comment is appreciated. Now I'm going to look for the play button. ha, ha.

Comment: Consider accepting the answer then, so users with a similar problem can see the solution. :) happy blending (alt + a plays and stops your animation)